# Count the number of occurrences of all the digits in the string S.?

Tags: c++, string

output format: string = 7714

0 0

1 1

2 0

3 0 .....

7 2 and so on till digit 9. Note: there will be new line after each digit occurence value. Alongside each digits same occurence is showing up which is 15 or 20 or 25.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    string s;
    cin>>s;
    int i,j;
    int c=0;
    int a;
    int l=s.length();
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        cin>>s[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=9;j++)
        {
        if(s[j]==1 || s[j]==2 || s[j]==3 || s[j]==4 || s[j]==5 || s[j]==6 || s[j]==7 || s[j]==8 || s[j]==9 || s[j]==0)
        {
            c++;
        }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<" "<<c<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try comparing them to '1' and so on... 1 is an int and converts to some weird character.

Comment: It looks like you need to study the difference between digits and numbers.

Comment: How will that help ?

Comment: Your question is unclear as well as `cin>>s;` and then the purpose of trying to read ` cin>>s[i];`

Comment: @macroland . we need to count the occurence of each digit in a string in the format i wrote abovr

Comment: @molbdnilo can you provide me with a better and correct solution as it compiled succesfully but giving wrong occurences .

Comment: there are functions like isdigit, isalpha. Why dont you use them and see if it is a digit or an alpha character?

Comment: Input
77150
Your Code's Output
0 15
1 15
2 15
3 15
4 15
5 15
6 15
7 15
8 15
9 15
Expected Correct Output
0 1
1 1
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 1
6 0
7 2
8 0
9 0
Compilation Log :
Compiled successfully.

Comment: @macroland But here the input is a string of digits not any alphabets or special characters .

Comment: @RitikSrivastava You seem to be under the impression that just because the program compiles without errors, that the program must work correctly.  Wrong.  All that means when a program compiles without errors is that there are no syntax errors.  There still can be logical errors in the program, and obviously your program contains such errors.  It is then *your* job, not ours, to debug the code.  Learning how to debug your own code is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.

Comment: @RitikSrivastava Do you know how to index a simple string? You can iterate over each character. Simply compare the character to a digit character, and increment an appropriate counter variable, such as `unsigned int count0, count1, count2, ... count 9;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that's cool . But here I told that I tried but not getting to correct solution as I'm also a beginner to this so I need to understand it from you people only who can guide me when I'm wrong

Comment: Well literally, the program can be written in 3 lines of code.  Do you know what an array is?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie . I'm not that new . So yeah I know . Next ?

Comment: @MPops  Why we need to convert characters to integer ? String contains integer only .

Comment: So apply some logic to how you would use an array.  The answer posted already gives a hint.  And if the sticking point is how to convert a digit character to a number, then focus solely on that.  When you find how to do that (and it should have been known already, if not examples are all over), then apply that knowledge to the program.

Comment: @Ritik Srivastava: Next: define an array of 10 integral elements, initialize it with 0s, and - for i = 0 .. s.length - increase each `s[i] - '0'`th element

Comment: @RitikSrivastava Your string contains printable characters (probably [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)). The character "1" does not have the decimal value 1, it's 49 in the ASCII encoding. That's why we need to convert characters to integers.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie I followed your advice and created a 3 liner. Thanks for the challenge :-)

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the additional information you included in the comments.

Comment: @StephanLechner  Can you explain s[i]- '0' ? What will it do exactly ?

Comment: @Blastfurnace . Oh ! Now I got the reason . Thanks . It better to explain a beginner than just showing off like some other here in the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since after one day all the comments and answers so far obviously could not help you, see the following simple solution.

The exercise targets people starting with C++, so I suppose it is better to use basic constructs like arrays and loops.

The array `counts` holds the counts of the digits, one for each possible digit; so the size of the array is 10. Note that the characters in the string are *not integral digits* from 0..9, but *characters* in (very likely) ASCII code from 48..57. The ASCII-code of character '0' is integral value 48, not integral value 0. So to get a range from 0..9, one has to substract 48 (or '0', which is the same as integral 48) from the respective character.
Hope it helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string s = "7714";
    int counts[10] =  { 0 };  // init all the counters with 0
    for (int i=0; i<s.length();i++) {  // iterate over the characters in s
        char c = s[i];
        if (isdigit(c)) {
            int index = c - '0'; // c is from '0' to '9' (i.e. ASCII codes 48..57); need it from 0..9; char('0') stands for int(49).
            counts[index]++;  // increment the counter representing the respective digit
        } else {
            std::cout << "invalid character (not a digit) in s" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << counts[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0: 0
1: 1
2: 0
3: 0
4: 1
5: 0
6: 0
7: 2
8: 0
```

Comment: Cannot we do for(i=0;i<s.length;i++) instead of char c : s because I'm not versed with this statement ?

Comment: Sure. see edited answer; but you should start getting familiar with these concepts, e.g. the "range-based for loop", which is heavily used in C++

Answer (score 1):

The power of algorithms . . .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // Get String from user
    std::string s; std::cin >> s;
    // This is what we want to search
    std::string digits("0123456789");

    // Do all the work in a one liner
    std::for_each(digits.begin(), digits.end(), [&s](const char c) { std::cout << c << ' ' << std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), c) << '\n'; });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did not try it out, but wouldn't this print a digit twice if it appears twice in digits, e.g. `digits("1001")`?

Comment: Maybe you mixed up. "digits" is the search string. In the input string, the characters will count according to the characters in the digits string. You could use "abc" for digits. Then it would count the a's, b's and c's.Simply test it in GDB online.

Answer (score -2):

Create an array of counters.

```
int counters[10]; //will store the counts of each instance.
                 //counters[0] will count the number of 0s, etc.
```

Convert each input character to integer.

```
look up how to do this on the internet.
```

Increment that index of counters array.

```
counters[the_converted_character_to_integer]++;
```

Comment: *look up how to do this on the internet.* probably covered in the C++ language text the asker is learning from as well. If the asker is NOT learning from a language text, well... They're gonna be at this a long long time.

Comment: @StephanLechner I left out bits of info (you may have realized) because I'm not willing to write the program for them without them showing at least some effort.

Comment: *look up how to do this on the internet.* While I appreciated the sentiment, answers are usually a lot better if they include this information.